# Do $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ and $g(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ have compact support in $\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, p-adic-number-theory

> Do $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ and $g(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ have compact support in $\Bbb Z_2$?

$f:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$ and $g:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$

$\Bbb Z_p$ is the p-adic integers and I understand the topology of any set $\Bbb Z_p$ is that of a Cantor set.

$q^{\nu_q(x)}$ is simply the largest power of some prime $q$ that divides $x$, e.g. $2^{\nu_2(24)}=8$

---

I understand compact support to mean the closure of the set of arguments for which the function is non-zero, is a compact set, so I'm assessing compact support in $\Bbb Z_2$ under the usual metric.

---

The values of $x$ for which $f(x)=0$  are $-\frac{2^m}{3}$

So my thinking is that none of these is in $\Bbb Z$ and therefore the closure of the set of arguments yielding nonzero $f$ still contains all of $\Bbb Z$, whose closure in $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$ is still $\Bbb Z_2$ which is compact, so $f(x)$ has compact support.

As for $g(x)$, and I could possibly do with some help showing this for sure but I think this function is zero nowhere because:

Let $x=2^m3^ry$

Then $g(2^m3^ry)=2^m3^{r+1}y+2^m3^r=2^m3^r(3y+1)$

This can only be zero for $y=-\frac13$, which $y$ cannot be since we have factored its powers of $3$ into $3^r$ therefore $g$ is nonzero for all arguments in $\Bbb Z_2$ which is compact so $g$ has compact support too.

Is that correct?

On a related note there seems to be freedom to define $q^{\nu_q(x)}$ as I see fit for $x=0$, although I should probably make some explicit choice as without one, it doesn't seem well-defined.  Implicit in the above, is that I have taken it to be $q^{\nu_q(0)}=1$.  How should $q^{\nu_p(0)}$ be best chosen?  Is there some common or more logical choice, e.g. that best-preserves continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_2$ is compact, so every closed subset of it is compact.  So every function on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has compact support.

(I would remark, though, that your definition of $g$ is meaningless since $3$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ so $\nu_3(x)$ has no meaning for an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  The obvious definition of $2^{\nu_2(0)}$ would be $0$, since $2^{\nu_2(x)}$ approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$.)

Comment: Thank-you in particular for $2^{\nu_2(0)}=0$ as I had come to the same conclusion but was a little uncomfortable with it. On your other point, I want to conclude $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere, but your statement about $\nu_3(x)$ is a real fly in the ointment. I was careless to use $p$. Is it now meaningful if I rewrite as I have done using $q$, which may or may not coincide with $p$?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that $\nu_3(x)$ is meaningless for $x\in\mathbb{Z}_2$...

Comment: I need a function on $\Bbb Z_2$ with exactly the properties of $3^{\nu_3(x)}$ because I need to preserve the properties of $g(x)$ on all numbers $\forall z\in Z:z\equiv\{1,2\}\pmod3$ but for it to map multiples of $3$ into $Z$, and for it to commute with $3x$ in the sense that $3\cdot g(x)=g(3x)$. I can see why $\nu_p(x)$ has special significance in $\Bbb Z_p$, a significance which is not there for $\nu_q(x):q\neq p$, which I think is the thrust of what you're saying. Is that the full extent of what you mean saying the function is meaningless?

Comment: _Every_ element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a multiple of $3$, so I have no idea what you are hoping for your function to accomplish.

Comment: Right, so there's something abstract going on I hadn't appreciated. I need a function $h(x)$ having the properties $3^{h(18)}=9$ etc.

Comment: $\nu_3$ has a perfectly good definition on $\mathbb{Z}_3$, just not on $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant.. no obvious definition for many of the elements of $\Bbb Z_2$